# Simultaneously `CREATE TABLE LIKE` in AWS Redshift and change a few of columns' default values

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-update, amazon-redshift, create-table, postgresql-copy

### Workflow

1. In a data import workflow, we are creating a staging table using [`CREATE TABLE LIKE` statement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_examples.html#r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW-create-a-temporary-table-that-is-like-another-table).

```sql
CREATE TABLE abc_staging (LIKE abc INCLUDING DEFAULTS);
```

2. Then, we run [`COPY`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) to import CSV data from S3 into the staging table.
3. The data in CSV is incomplete. Namely, there are fields `partition_0`, `partition_1`, `partition_2` which are missing in the CSV file; we fill them in like this:

```sql
UPDATE
  abc_staging
SET
  partition_0 = 'BUZINGA',
  partition_1 = '2018',
  partition_2 = '07';
```

### Problem

This query seems expensive (takes ≈20 minutes oftentimes), and I would like to avoid it. That could have been possible if I could configure `DEFAULT` values on these columns when creating the `abc_staging` table. I did not find any method as to how that can be done; nor any explicit indication that is impossible. So perhaps this is still possible but I am missing how to do that?

### Alternative solutions I considered

#### Drop these columns and add them again

That would be easy to do, but [`ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_COL_ex-add-drop.html) only adds columns to the end of the column list. In `abc` table, they are not at the end of the column list, which means the schemas of `abc` and `abc_staging` will mismatch. That breaks [`ALTER TABLE APPEND`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND.html) operation that I use to move data from staging table to the main table.

**Note.** Reordering columns in `abc` table to alleviate this difficulty [will require recreating](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3277/140654) the huge `abc` table which I'd like to avoid.

#### Generate the staging table creation script programmatically with proper columns and get rid of `CREATE TABLE LIKE`

I will have to do that if I do not find any better solution.

#### Fill in the `partition_*` fields in the original CSV file

That is possible but will break backwards compatibility (I already have perhaps hundreds thousands of files in there). Harder but manageable.

Comment: You know that `UPDATE` will complete unsort the table?  this may well be why it's slow.  How many rows, roughly speaking, are you loading?  Do you `VACUUM` afterwards?  what are the column encodings in the original `abc` table?  (I'll need to check if they are carried over correctly by CTL - I think they may be, but Redshift has a very nasty habit of silently changing column encodings to its choices, and it makes very poor choices, so it's something you need make sure of; the docs says nothing about this, which is worrying).  Also note CTL omits bringing over PKs and FKs.

Comment: - I was not aware about that behavior of `UPDATE`. But I do see that `UPDATE` queries are quite slow. I run `COPY` and `UPDATE` in one transaction.
- No I do not `VACUUM` after the import, but `svv_table_info.vacuum_sort_benefit` shows 0 for `abc` table.
- The number of rows varies from perhaps 500 to perhaps 50 000 per file. Of course I create a separate staging table per every file. Multiple files can be (and typically are) imported simultaneously.
- Most of the columns are `VARCHAR` and encoding is `zstd`.
- In `abc_staging`, the same `zstd` encoding is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are finding you are not creating a table exactly LIKE the original and Redshift doesn't let you ALTER a column's default value.  Your proposed path is likely the best (define the staging table explicitly).

Since I don't know your exact situation other paths might be better so me explore a bit. First off when you UPDATE the staging table you are in fact reading every row in the table, invalidating that row, and writing a new row (with new information) at the end of the table.  This leads to a lot of invalidated rows.  Now when you do ALTER TABLE APPEND all these invalidated rows are being added to your main table.  Unless you vacuum the staging table before hand. So you may not be getting the value you want out of ALTER TABLE APPEND.

You may be better off INSERTing the data onto your main table with an ORDER BY clause.  This is slower than the ALTER TABLE APPEND statement but you won't have to do the UPDATE so the overall process could be faster.  You could come out further ahead because of reduced need to VACUUM.  Your situation will determine if this is better or not.  Just another option for your list.

I am curious about your UPDATE speed.  This just needs to read and then write every row in the staging table.  Unless the staging table is very large it doesn't seem like this should take 20 min.  Other activity could be creating this slowdown.  Just curious.

Another option would be to change your main table to have these 3 columns last (yes this would be some work).  This way you could add the columns to the staging table and things would line up for ALTER TABLE APPEND.  Just another possibility.

Comment: The slowdowns are happening when I am importing a few hundred files at the same time. That might very well be the reason. Thank you for the detailed explanation. I was aware `UPDATE` was expensive but I thought it would work on one column only instead of invalidating whole row.

Comment: Because Redshift is columnar and compressed updating one value may need more space than the original value.  This would then require that all the rest of the columns data be "pushed" down to make this extra space.  This would be very expensive.  So they invalidate the row and recreate it at the end of the table which is much cheaper for a few UPDATEs.  Since your current process reads and writes all the data anyway, you may be better off just doing an INSERT.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that explanation is incorrect.  Redshift uses MVCC.  The original row is retained, but has its end generation set.  A new version of that row, with the updated value, is appended to the table.  The entire row, across all columns, has to have this done, because often the only way you can rematerialize a row is by knowing the row number; so every column has to have its value in the correct row number.  You can't move one column independently of the others.

Comment: No, MVCC operates at the block level, not row level.  So when the UPDATE is committed (blocks written and made available to others) and some other session still needs the pre-UPDATE version of the blocks it can still get them.  These are two completely different concepts.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think MVCC at least is in part row-level; you can see the insert/delete xid columns on a per-row basis, and indeed, as I understand MVCC, it could only make sense on a per-row basis.  Redshift however regards blocks as immutable.  It's as this point I'm unclear; an update occurs, and I can see the end generation for MVCC is set, but how is this done?  my current guess is the original block is tombstoned and you then get two new blocks, one old (old value, MVCC end gen set), one new.  What this is, is the mapping of row-level MVCC onto an immutable-block implementation.

Comment: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.jefclaes.be/amazon-redshift-fundamentals/aws-redshift-fundamentals.html#multiversion-concurrency-control

Comment: I'm reading it now.  I may be wrong, but I think he is mistaken.  There is no block-level version number for MVCC in the system tables.  It's row-level.  The only block-level information is a boolean, indicating tombstoned or not tombstoned.  I think he may either be writing rather loosely.  Reading some more - he doesn't properly kno what slices are, I suspect - it reads like he thinks they are fairly hard subdivisions of resource.

Comment: Yeah - I may be wrong, but I really disagee completely with how he's described MVCC.  It may even be when he says "it" he means the row, not the block.  I think what he's said is *not* correct for blocks.  Separately from that, what he's written in the section "Query Plans" is very strange.  Either he doesn't know about compilation (which I find unlikely) or he's trying to sort-of-explain but without going into detail - which in turn has to raise the question if this approach is being taken elsewhere (such as MVCC).

Comment: @MaxGanzII perhaps you know of another source of information about how Redshift works internally? I think I did read through the AWS documentation on Redshift a while ago but I do not believe it goes into that much detail. Would be useful to obtain a better understanding of the tool I am using.

Comment: I hold an extremely dim view of the official docs.  I think them superficial, lightweight, sometimes flatly incorrect, not reviewed by technical staff and usually misleading because they (like Support and all information from AWS about Redshift) obfuscate anything which is not a strength.  I mainly know about Redshift in part through being a database kernel developer and so having an idea of what goes on, and in part by investigation - actually writing code and seeing what is happening and figuring out what most likely is going on.

Comment: I avoid actually asking the devs questions about how things work because if they tell me, I'm then bound to keep that information private unless they okay it going public - and there is, in my view, something of a culture of secrecy - and I could usually have worked whatever it was out for myself and then been able to speak about it in public.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution turned to be adding the necessary `partition_*` fields to the source CSV files.

After employing that change and removing the `UPDATE` from the importer pipeline, the performance has greatly improved. Imports now take ≈10 minutes each in total (that encompasses `COPY`, `DELETE` duplicates and `ALTER TABLE APPEND`).

Disk space is no longer climbing up to 100%.

Thanks everyone for help!